# How to design my models?

Tags: django

I have an issue. I don't know how to build my model according to the fair way of Django.

I have 3 models : Team, Plateform and Games.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=False)
    description = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True)
    games = models.ManyToManyField(Games, verbose_name="Jeu")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Créateur")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")

class Plateform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="Plateforme")
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="Abréviation")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")

class Games(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="GUID")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Titre")
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to='media/games/', validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Logo du jeu")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
    plateform = models.ManyToManyField(Plateform, verbose_name="Plateforme")
```

So :

- Games own to many Plateforms
- Teams play many Games

My question is, how to determine which Games on which Plateforms a Team is currently playing ?
Because I have to know if a team is playing a Game on a particular Plateform or several.

I think I need a new class like :

```
class Relation(models.Model):
   team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
   plateform = models.ForeignKey(Plateform)
   game = models.ForeignKey(Games)
```

But isn't there a better idea according to Django ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use extra fields in m2m relation:

[Many to Many - Extra fields doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

you will lose few options available on your m2m querysets but it will solve your problem in a proper way.

your relation model should be something like this:

```
class Relation(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Games)
    platforms = models.ManyToManyField(Plateform)
```

and in your `Team` model add `through`:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=False)
    description = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True)
    games = models.ManyToManyField(Games, verbose_name="Jeu", through='Relation')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Créateur")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
```

now you can get which games a team plays and what platforms they play on.
examples:

```
team1 = Team.objects.first()
games = team1.games.all()
for game in games:
    platforms = game.platforms.all()
    for platform in platforms:
        print(platform)
```

you can do it in other ways like add a field for each platform in your `Relation` model and etc ... but in general this the way you can do this by the use of the features that django has provide.
They might be other options, even better than mine but this is an option to consider.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I think the other possibility and may be the simplest, is to add so many time a game that it exists on a plateform.

Comment: i think this is the simplest way because it will solve your problems on accessing data later which you need less codes. also you won't lose much of django features. but it's your choice.

Comment: Your link is quite interesting. I will try if ManyToManyField.through_fields is a solution for this situation.